# NA values on Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, boxplot, box

so I'm working with python and data frames.
I have a list of movies from which I create a subset and I'm trying to plot or just figure out the mean for that matter but there is a lot of missing information and the frame just has an "NA" instead of data.

I use np library to ignore does values but I still get an error saying the type of input is not supported by isfinite

```
    data = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\Bubbles\Documents\CS241\week 13\movies.csv")
Action = data[(data.Action == 1)]
Action = Action[np.isfinite(Action.budget)]

print(Action.budget.mean())
```

the budget list would just contain "NA" and integers as possible values

Comment: What return `Action.budget.isnull()` ? There are `True` for missing values?

Comment: it returns false for the whole list